# I'm having troubles with file_get_contents("php://input")

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm developing a Codeigniter application and using AngularJS for the frontend.

I'm getting the POST data through `file_get_contents("php://input")` in PHP 7.4.6 but the JSON comes with the number 1 at the end.

Example:

```
{"credentials":{"email":"blablabla@hotmail.com","password":"12345678"}}1
```

I've also tried using `$this->input->post()`, but it returns the following:

```
Array
(
)
1
```

Following is the function that I use to get data from POST:

```php
public function getInputAngular()
{
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata, true);

    foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
        $request[$key] = str_replace("'", '', $value);
    }

    return $request;
}
```

I'm calling the previous function when I do the request to the following function inside the CI controller:

```php
public function handleLogin()
{
    $data = $this->funcoes_generica->getInputAngular(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way I was printing the data.

How I was doing:

```php
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($postdata);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

The right way to do this:

```php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($postdata);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```